# pgfkeys: Is it possible to achieve a "dictionary-like" input method for subkeys (without much parsing effort)?

Tags: pgfkeys

### Problem Description

Currently I am working on a template for scientific theses. The goal is to automate a lot of tedious settings (like pdf metadata, styling/accent colors, title page etc.) by giving the user one or multiple specific setup commands. 
The first prototype was using the `scrreprt` as base document class and `komavars` for storing/logically processing the data. Not only is in my opinion this approach a bit "hacky" (since `komavars` are normally only defined in the `scrlttr` document classes and have to be loaded into other document classes via the `scrletter` package), but most importantly the user experience with having to setup dozens of `komavars` via e.g. `\setkomavar{mt::author::name}{John Doe}` was not to good.
Since the project is aimed to bring a better user experience to beginner/intermediate LaTeX users (the target audience is not necessary LaTeX fans, but people who have to use it for an academic thesis and are not used to LaTeX), I was wondering if one could change this.
The first experiments with `pgfkeys` are very promising. Until now, I could implement all the functionality I needed without running into problems. The current functionality implementation principle is shown
in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    /mt/.cd,
    author/name/.initial,
    author/place of birth/.initial,
}

\newcommand*\setup[1]{\pgfqkeys{/mt}{#1}}

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/mt/author/name}, %
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/mt/author/place of birth}%
}

\setup{
    author/name=John Doe, 
    author/place of birth = New York
}

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

The functionality is like desired; however, the user data input method via

```
\setup{
    author/name=John Doe, 
    author/place of birth = New York
}
```

feels still a bit too clunky/clumsy for someone who might not like LaTeX.

### Question:

Is it possible to achieve a "dictionary-like" input method for subkeys, without having to do much parsing with for example `xparse`? Is something like

```
\setup{
    author = {
        name = John Doe,
        place of birth = New York
    }
}
```

easily achievable?

Comment: I had a similar issue at work and flattened the keys into one namespace. A lot can be achieved by being careful with naming. You can use a dot like `author.name=John Doe`, `author.place=New York` etc. Gets rid of a lot of curlies!

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: That is in general a good suggestion. However, there are specific reasons why I am interested in a version with the curly brackets: Among them are the aspect of different visual separation achievable by tabbing, similarity to the `JSON` format (easier parsing, especially when the potential future inclusion of `JSON` data might become a requirement for the project) and more consistency to the rest of the LaTeX options syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define key `/mt/author` to treat its argument as keys with default path `/mt/author`:

```
author/.code={\pgfqkeys{/mt/author}{#1}}
```

Using `\pgfqkeys` instead of `\pgfkeysalso` (or its equivalence `/.style` handler), the default path is restored after `\pgfqkeys`.
`/mt/author` can also be defined as

```
author/.ecode={\noexpand\pgfqkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}}
```

This latter case is tricker, but it saves you from repeating (current) key path if you have many key nodes similar to `/mt/author` to define.

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
    /mt/.cd,
    author/.code={\pgfqkeys{/mt/author}{#1}},
    % or
    % author/.ecode={\noexpand\pgfqkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}},
    author/name/.initial,
    author/place of birth/.initial,
}

\newcommand*\setup[1]{\pgfqkeys{/mt}{#1}}

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/mt/author/name}, %
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/mt/author/place of birth}%
}

\setup{
    author = {
        name=John Doe, 
        place of birth = New York
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

typesets

> John Doe, New York

Comment: Thank you very much @muzimuzhi Z for this solution. It solves all the problems. However, for the specific project I think I might prefer the general `expl3` solution suggested by @Ulrike Fischer, which seems to be more flexible in the long run.

Comment: The answer by @muzimuzhi Z solves all the problems and uses the tools that were required in the original question. That is why I marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @dsacre I wouldn't say that expl3 is more flexible, pgfkeys is a quite powerful package. But I'm not really getting along with it, it confuses me that setting and defining keys use the same command, for me the expl3 code is clearer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With LaTeX, I try to stick to the less packages required, the better approach. So if I do not have to load `pgfkeys`, I see that as a win :-)
The flexibility remark was only concerning the possibility to gain access to two possible input methods with `expl3` out of the box (no additional coding). The `expl3` syntax with tokens is still weird to me, but I cannot decide which way confuses me less, since I am currently neither used to the ``expl3` syntax, nor the `pgfkeys` one...

Comment: (+1) That's how I do it everytime. In my opinion, the `.ecode` reason screams for a handler: `\pgfkeys{/handlers/.is setter/.code=\pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\noexpand\pgfqkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{##1}}}` → `author/.is setter`.

Comment: @dsacre There are things you can't do with the `expl3` version which are easy in `pgfkeys` and vice-versa. There are also things which are a pain to do in one of them, but simple in the other. And vice-versa. For example, `.style args` can be very useful. So can the ability to define custom key handlers, which aren't possible in `expl3`. But grouping and selectively setting I find much easier in `expl3`. Not to mention expansion. Really, it just depends what makes sense in any given case.

Answer (score 3):

With the in-built key-handler it would work too. Unrelated but do not use the minimal class for such examples, it is too minimal for most cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{dsacre}
 {
   author .code:n = {\keys_set:nn {dsacre/author}{#1}},
   author / name .tl_set:N = \l_dsacre_author_name,
   author / place~of~birth .tl_set:N = \l_dsacre_author_birth,
 }

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \l_dsacre_author_name,~ %
    \l_dsacre_author_birth%
}

\newcommand*\setup[1]{\keys_set:nn{dsacre}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\setup{
    author/name=John Doe, 
    author/place of birth = New York
}


\test

\setup{
    author = {
        name = Jane Bar,
        place of birth = London
    }
}
    
\test    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and the tip about the `minimal` document class. 
For the context of the project, I would prefer this solution. 
Is it also possible with this approach to allow for detection of the `author.name = John Doe` suggestion by @Yiannis Lazarides ?

Comment: If possible, the goal would be to allow for multiple different configuration input methods, so that the user could choose which one is better. Of course this leads to (visual) inconsistency between code written by different authors.

Comment: you can naturally define also keys `author.name` but they wouldn't come so naturally like slashes which are part of the expl3 (and pgfkeys) path syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of those people who may not like LaTeX but I like TeX. Your suggested format of `\setup` seems to me still a bit too clunky/clumsy, but I tried to implement it using OpTeX's key-value macros. Just for fun.

```
\def\setup#1{\readkv{#1}%
   \readkv{\expanded{\kv{author}}}%
   \readkv{\expanded{%
      mt/author/name=\kv{name},
      mt/author/place of birth=\kv{place of birth}
   }}
}
\def\test{%
   \kv{mt/author/name},
   \kv{mt/author/place of birth}.%
}

\setup{%
    author = {%
        name = John Doe,
        place of birth = New York
    }
}

\test  % prints: John Doe, New York.

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer extends [Ulrike Fischer's `expl3`/`l3keys` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700769) to support a pseudo dot syntax mentioned by @Yiannis Lazarides in [question comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700759/pgfkeys-is-it-possible-to-achieve-a-dictionary-like-input-method-for-subkeys/700766?noredirect=1#comment1742330_700759)

```
author.name = <...>, author.place of birth = <...>
```

(Odd to see spaces in "property names".)

The pseudo dot syntax is achieved by providing a customized `unknown` key.

`pgfkeys` has a similar handler `.unknown` hence is capable to support pseudo dot syntax too. The condition that full key path in `l3keys` is a `expl3` string makes the implementation in `l3keys` easier and more robust (no need to look out active dot `.`).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{dsacre}
 {
   author                  .code:n   = {\keys_set:nn {dsacre/author}{#1}},
   author / name           .tl_set:N = \l_dsacre_author_name,
   author / place~of~birth .tl_set:N = \l_dsacre_author_birth,
   unknown                 .code:n   =
    {
      \str_replace_all:Nnn \l_keys_path_str {.} {/}
      % \keys_set:ne { } % requires l3kernel 2023-10-10 or newer
      \exp_args:Nne \keys_set:nn { }
        { \l_keys_path_str = { \exp_not:o { \l_keys_value_tl } } }
    }
 }

\newcommand{\test}{
    \l_dsacre_author_name,~ 
    \l_dsacre_author_birth
}

\newcommand*\setup[1]{\keys_set:nn{dsacre}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setup{
    author/name=John Doe, 
    author/place of birth = New York
}

\test

\setup{
    author = {
        name = Jane Bar,
        place of birth = London
    }
}

\test

\setup{
    author.name = Tom,
    author.place of birth = Tokyo
}

\test
\end{document}
```

The output PDF will consist of three lines in main body

> John Doe, New York
> Jane Bar, London
> Tom, Tokyo

It looks like OP will soon be asking for a connivence interface to test if each of some keys is ever set by the user at least once.

Comment: On my machine, this code does not compile. I get a undefined control sequence warning and no output.

Comment: @dsacre Which control sequence is undefined (what the warning said)? Guessing it's `\keys_set:ne`, which needs `l3kernel` 2023-10-10 or newer. You can replace it with `\exp_args:Nne \keys_set:nn`.

Comment: Yes, it seems like `\keys_set:ne` was the issue. After changing it according to your suggestion, it now works on my machine.

Comment: @dsacre The error message clearly show which control sequence is undefined (the last one in the line like "l.34 <tokens>"), so you can drop the "seems like" phrase.

Comment: I was just quickly testing the code with TeXStudio (without saving the tex file), which in this particular case did not specify the line number in the GUI (which it normally does); in fact, it only did give the very vague message `Undefined control sequence. }`. That was all of it (yes, that was the complete message), nothing more or less. So at the time of writing, I did not have the confirmation what exactly was causing the issue. That is why I preferred to stay vague with "seems like".

Comment: @dsacre In the lower-left log pane, click to show the "Log File" tab. Then click specific row in "Issues" tab to jump to the position of that error in "Log File" tab, and check out its full error message.